# Permissions to have a token?

Tags: force.com, api, security, permissions

I know how to reset my token once i have it, and how to navigate to it. What I can't find is  what permissions/lack of restrictions do I need on my profile to  allow me to have a token? is it a lack of IP restrictions on my profile? What's going on here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right track, You need to have API Enabled checked to true on your user profile.

[image: API Enabled Checkbox]

Comment: Wow.  You beat me by 8 seconds.  lol.  Good job +1

Comment: Boom :) quick on the trigger today. I don't have a fancy arrow though.

Comment: Tokens don't matter if you *do* have IP restrictions, since you're not allowed to access salesforce.com from outside those networks.

Answer (score 4):

To get a security token, the profile must have the 'API Enabled' permission

[image]

**From the documentation**

> When a user's password is changed, the user's security token is
>   automatically reset. The user will experience a blocked login until he
>   or she adds the automatically-generated security token to the end of
>   his or her password or enters the new password after the administrator
>   adds their IP address to the organization's list of trusted IP
>   addresses.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_concepts_security.htm

Comment: what about IP range restrictions?

Comment: Jut added a quote from documentation around Security tokens to answer

Comment: Consider three zones of access: approved, unknown, or disapproved. Approved zones are those in the Network Access list or in the IP range restrictions, disapproved locations are any area outside IP range restrictions, and unknown locations are neither approved or disapproved. Tokens will only help you get in if you're in an unknown location, and not a disapproved location.